# How to remove the carriage return character from CKEditor after the image is being added?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, html-entities

When i paste the image on the editor which is already having some content, the editor automatically adds the carriage return character after the image, but when i paste the image, without any content on the editor, it doesn't add the carriage return character.

Here is the content

```
<p>some content</p>

<p><img src="http://some-url-link-to-image"/></p>↵
```

I want to get rid of this carriage return character, Even this happens on the http://ckeditor.com/demo